# Returning values from a mocked angular service and calling through

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am having some problems figuring out how to write tests correctly for a controller method that relies on calling an Angular service and returning a certain value, but, I need to be able to test the code within the .then() function after.

Here is the basic idea:

```
// Controller

$scope.myMethod = function() {
    methodName.connect().then(
        function(returnValue) {
            if (returnValue.prop === 1) {
                $scope.callMade = true;
                $rootScope.$emit('callWasMade');
            }
        },
        function() {
            $rootScope.$emit('callWasNotMade');
        }
    );
};
```

So I want to test the call to the method on the $scope, call the methodName.connect() function but I want to mock a response (overwriting returnValue) but still have the function run as normal. Something like:

```
// Test

describe('connecting to method', function() {
    it('should do nothing when returnValue.prop does not equal 1', function() {
        spyOn(methodName, 'connect').and.returnValue({ prop: 2 });
        scope.myMethod();
        expect(scope.callMade).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it('should pass when returnValue.prop does equal 1', function() {
        spyOn(methodName, 'connect').and.returnValue({ prop: 1 });
        scope.myMethod();
        expect(scope.callMade).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Except this returns

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'methodName.connect().then') (...)
```

How can I control the output from methodName.connect in this way?

Thanks.

Comment: Because `methodName` is not attached on the scope, you can create a spy like `spyOn(methodName, 'connect')`. Your problem is that your codes doesn't seperate the concerns. So it's hard to test.

Comment: So I should attached methodName to the scope? In this example, methodName is meant to represent a service.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that methodName is a service. So just mock the this service in the controller injected.

Also, I have a question for your controller. Why `myMethod` is attached to scope, but not the controller itself (like: `myMethod = function() {}`)?

The below codes should work:

```
describe('connecting to method', function() {
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    // create a mock service attached to controller
    methodName = {
      connect: function () {
      }
    };

    spyOn(methodName, 'connect').and.returnValue({ prop: 2 });

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('yourCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      methodName : methodName 
    });
  }));

  it('should do nothing when returnValue.prop does not equal 1', function() {
    // here I consider myMethod is a method of controller, but not of the scope
    myMethod();
    expect(scope.callMade).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Qianyue, I still get this error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'myMethod.connect().then')`. In this case, myMethod is a service that will connect to a websocket and return a fulfilled promise with an object, I then need to test if the `returnValue.prop` equals 1 in order to set some scoped variables. If it isn't it should do nothing.

Comment: @AMcI Note that here I just give you an idea about how to test a controller with service. And my codes suppose that in your controller, myMethod is under controller, but not in the scope. Can you create a jsfiddle to show your problem? I can't tell where is the problem because there is not enough infomation for me.

Comment: Hi Qianyue - After some thought over the weekend I think I might be going about this the wrong way as you said, I think I need to separate the concerns more. Thank you for your help!